# My subreport code only runs for the first record

Tags: ms-access

I have a report that has two subreports in a 1:N relationship, one of which also has a subreport in a 1:N relationship.  I've made the report_load functions in all the subreports public, and then have the parent report call them so that they will run when the parent report is run, as per the following instructions:

https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/vba-on-subreport-does-not-fire.294207/

All levels of the report are running the same public function:

```
    Public Sub asterisks(rpt As Report, PK As String, ID As String, Date_Modified As Date)
Dim SQL As String, db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
SQL = "SELECT SOURCEFIELD FROM AUDIT WHERE Edit_Date > #" & Date_Modified & "# AND SOURCETABLE = """ & PK & """ AND RECORDID = """ & ID & """"
Debug.Print (SQL)

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        Do Until rs.EOF = True
            Dim ctl As Control
            For Each ctl In rpt
                If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
                    If rs!SourceField = ctl.Name Then
                        ctl.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    End If
                End If
            Next ctl
            Set ctl = Nothing
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Which basically iterates through every textfield control in the report and colors it red if it showed up on the Audit table. (The Audit table from this solution: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/a-simple-solution-for-tracking-changes-to-access-data/)

What happens is that if a control is found in the audit table (in this case part_name), it would not only color the record that was changed, but ALL part names on the report.

How can I call the load function and make it so it runs this code for each record in the report?

Comment: Call code in Format event of section that contains the controls you want to modify properties for. Will trigger for only PrintPreview or direct to printer, not ReportView. Consider using Conditional Formatting.

Comment: I expect code in that referenced discussion is not setting properties of controls in detail section.

Answer (score 0):

Open event will run for report even when used as subreport.

However, if you want VBA to dynamically set control properties per record based on some condition, that requires code to be in Format or Print events for the section where controls are located. Those events trigger for only PrintPreview or direct to printer, not ReportView.

For conditionally setting font color, background color, text emphasis of textbox or combobox, I recommend using Conditional Formatting. A function in a general module can be called by CF rule.